# Automapper of collections into entity gives error that collections are already tracked

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I am trying to use automapper to map an a large DTO with many nested collections into an entity for saving into the database.

I have my DTO structure fairly similar to my entity structure.

eg.

```
LogbookDTO -> Logbook
LogbookSessionDTO -> LogbookSession
LogbookSessionSectionDTO -> LogbookSessionSection
....

public class LogbookDto {
 ICollection<LogbookSessionDTO> Sessions;
}

public class Logbook {
 ICollection<LogbookSession> Sessions;
}
```

Anytime I wish to save the mapped entity, EF gives me an error saying that its already tracked.

My steps are:

```
var logbook = _repository.GetById(logbookDto.Id);
Mapper.Map<Logbook>(logbookDto, logbook);
_repository.SaveChanges();
```

and every time I get this error:

```
 The instance of entity type 'Session' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 3}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
```

Comment: [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection)

Comment: Yea I looked into that, but couldn't get a good example of how to use it?  I am using EF Core 2.1

Comment: The README is pretty instructive; there is no effort shown in your question.

Comment: AutoMapper.Collections doesn't support EF Core

Comment: Yep, no effort.

Comment: hehe ok.  So how do I get this working on EF core?

Comment: What's the code of `GetById`?